# does it make sense to unit-test HttpApplication in aspNet mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

does it make sense to unit-test HttpApplication in aspNet mvc 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean - "does it make sense for me to unit test the HttpApplication class itself" - no. Not unless you are a developer on the ASP.NET team. Generally, you should be unit testing the code you are writing, not other people's.

However, if you mean "does it make sense for me to unit test my classes that depend on HttpApplication", then very possibly yes. It may be you have classes for which it makes a lot of sense to mock out (or otherwise fake) the HttpApplication class in order to assert that your own classes are behaving correctly.

Comment: Would you define IMyFunkyHttpApplication interface and then implement the interface in MyFunkyMvcApplication : IMyFunkyHttpApplication? This isn't my idea. I'm looking at somebody's code and wondering what the point is.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly: it is quite common to have an interface and a concrete implementation that implements the interface. The main reason for doing this is to decouple the consumers of your code from the actual implementation. In other words - where your code uses SomeDependency, it actually calls it through ISomeDependency. When you come to test, you can now mock out this dependency. This lets you test just your consumer code, without testing someone else's code in the dependency. It also lets you assert that your consumer calls the down to the dependency correctly.

Comment: I agree that HttpApplication itself should not be tested. However, I would definitely test any application specific logic stored inside a child of HttpApplication (usually inside Global.asax.cs). In MVC project, that class holds the configuration code, in webforms it contains application level event handlers.  Mocking helps a lot in this situation, or creating fakes manually

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to mock it if you're going to be using it in a unit test.

I would do it like this:

1: add a public static property/method to MvcApplication (in global.cs)

```
  public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

2: Create an interface

```
 public Interface IApplication 
    {
      string MyProperty {get;set;}
    }
```

3: Create a wrapper class for you MvcApplication and implement the interface

```
public class MvcApplicationWrapper: IApplication 
{
    public string MyProperty 
                {
                  get{
                 return MvcApplication.MyPropetry;

                   }
                set{
                MvcApplication.MyPropetry = value;
                  }

                 }
}
```

4: Create a public property on the controller to lazy load the IApplication

```
private IApplication app;
public IApplication Application{ 
get{
if(app == null){
app = new MvcApplicationWrapper();
}
return app;
}
set
{
app = value;
}
}
```

5: when you are unit testing, create a Mocked IApplication and set the Application property of the controller

```
var controller = new Controller();
controler.Application = new MockApplication();
/* do you tests */
```